# Autofac cannot resolve my Registered generic service

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, ioc-container

I've registered my generic interface in Autofac, but as I resolve it exception is thrown.

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'MyCLI.Command.ICommandHandler`1[[MyCLI.Command.ICommand, MyCLI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered.
>
> > To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

### Program.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var container = builder.RegisterTypes();
        var invoker = new Invoker(container);
        var command = TypeHelper.GetCommandByDescriptor("LS");
        invoker.Dispatch(command);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

### Service Registration

```
    public static IContainer RegisterTypes(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (ICommandHandler<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

### Resolve Service

```
public class Invoker : IInvoker
{
    private readonly IContainer container;
    public Invoker(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Dispatch<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
    {
        //if (!container.IsRegistered(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))) return;
        var candidate = container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<T>>();
        candidate.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

### GetCommandByDescriptor

```
    public static ICommand GetCommandByDescriptor(string descriptor)
    {
        var classes = GetAllCommands();
        var command = classes.First(x => x.GetType()
                        .GetCustomAttributes<CommandDescriptorAttribute>().First().CommandName.Equals(descriptor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return command;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the type returned from `TypeHelper.GetCommandByDescriptor("LS");` is registered with the container? What does that call actually return? Because from the exception it looks like it returns `ICommand` and not the actual concrete implementation.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It returns `ICommand`. I corrected it to  `invoker.Dispatch((dynamic)command);`

Comment: The generics is working against you here because of the return type. You would need to extract the actual type of T, construct the generic type desired and then resolve that. Looks like some reflection is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, thank to @Nkosi.
As I return `ICommand` from `GetCommandByDescriptor(string descriptor)` the type `T` in Dispatch Method would be from `ICommand` type which is actually not registered, I should return a type which have implemented `ICommand` e.g. `ListOfDirectoryCommand`.

As well I go like this:

```
invoker.Dispatch((dynamic)command);
```

So the type of `command` would be specified in run time.