# Autofac not resolving service with generic type

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a .NET Core 3.1 generic host that uses the mediator pattern to handle messages:

```
public interface IMessageDispatcher {
  Task Dispatch<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : Message;
}

public class MessageDispatcher : IMessageDispatcher {
  private readonly IServiceProvider _container;

  public MessageDispatcher(IServiceProvider container) {
    _container = container;
  }

  public async Task Dispatch<TMessage>(TMessage message) {
    var handler = (IMessageHandler<TMessage>) _container.GetService(typeof(IMessageHandler<TMessage>));
    await handler.Handle(message);
  }
}

public interface IMessageHandler<TMessage> where TMessage : Message {
  Task Handle(TMessage message);
}

public class MyMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<MyMessage> {
  public Task Handle(MyMessage message) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

The message handlers are registered with Autofac, as follows:

```
private static void AutoRegisterMessageHandlers(ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly domainAssembly) {
  builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(domainAssembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IMessageHandler<>));
}
```

If I run the above as-is, then the call to `_container.GetService` returns a null with the obvious `NullReferenceException` when I call the `Handle` method; however, if I put a breakpoint in before I call `Handle`, and run the following from the Immediate window in Visual Studio:

```
_container.GetService(typeof(IMessageHandler<MyMessage>));
```

then the expected message handler is returned, which suggests that the message handler is registered properly, it's just that when I try to resolve the message handler using the generic type

```
_container.GetService(typeof(IMessageHandler<TMessage>));
```

that things go wrong. Is there anything I'm doing obviously wrong?

**Update**

As per the accepted answer, I was receiving my messages from a message queue and deserialising them, so I had no concrete type:

```
var message = Deserialiser.Deserialise<Message>(rawXmlFromQueue);
await Dispatch(message);
```

Since there was no concrete type for `message`, Autofac didn't have enough information to locate the registered message handler, and returned `null`. The solution then was to cast the message to `dynamic`, and through the magic of C#'s type system, that was sufficient to convert the generic type into its concrete implementation:

```
var message = Deserialiser.Deserialise<Message>(rawXmlFromQueue);
await Dispatch((dynamic) message);
```

Comment: using `Service Locators` is a anti-pattern. see [docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#use-relationship-types-not-service-locators)

Comment: It's quite valid if you're doing e.g. CQRS and you don't want to inject a dozen command/query handlers into your controller; just so long as you know what you're letting yourself in for with that extra step of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resolve an open generic.

The problem you mention is you can't do this:

```cs
container.GetService(typeof(ICommandHandler<TMessage>))
```

But DI isn't magic, it's just another way to construct stuff. You also can't do:

```cs
new CommandHandler<TMessage>()
```

That is, unless you know what `TMessage` is, this doesn't make sense. You need a concrete type there.

However, beyond that, it's hard to figure out what's going on. The question is missing a lot.

- It mentions the call to `container. GetService` is returning null but not what you're trying to resolve when it's returning null.
- All the sample code shows `MessageHandler` but the examples you're running in the debugger are `CommandHandler`. There's not enough to know if that's a typo or part of the problem.

In any case, I hope that gives you some ideas on what to look at.

Comment: Sorry, that `CommandHandler` is a typo; I've fixed that.

Comment: The command is being deserialised from a message queue, and even then it's only being deserialised as a `Message`, rather than the concrete type. So I think this is where my problem is coming in, as you say. If I look at e.g. `message.GetType()` then it is indeed a `MyMessage`, but I guess Autofac doesn't have enough information to get the expected message handler. Any suggestions for how to square that particular circle?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some reflection work with `message.GetType()` and `Type.MakeGenericType` to create the right closed generic to resolve. That's app code, not something DI will somehow bridge.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668756/319980 - cast the deserialised message to `dynamic` _before_ calling the `Dispatch(TMessage)` method.